# What is the plural of the word "index"?

Tags: grammatical-number

What is the plural of the word "index"? It seems that there are two that are acceptable: "indexes" and "indices". I happen to prefer "indices" but I was wondering if one was generally preferred over the other.

I am using "index" as a programming term to indicate the position of an element in a array.