# How is "deque" commonly pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, programming

*deque* is a standard container in the C++ programming language. Its name stands for Double Ended QUEue. I am wondering how this word should be pronounced:

- like deck (this is how I've pronounced it so far)
- like dequeue
- like Dee-Ee-queue

I realize that this word is not in the dictionaries. I just want to know how most programmers pronounce it. Hope it's on topic.

Comment: I've always heard "deck". But I wouldn't worry too much about it- you'll find that different programmers pronounce things differently, just because you can go a long time without saying programming words out loud. Until recently, I said "earl" instead of "URL". Yesterday I had a conversation about whether "var" rhymed with "chair" or "car".

Comment: @KevinWorkman Well, that last one is easy-peasy: `var` rhymes with `char`, of course! ;-)

Comment: the defined pronunciation is "deck". But since it is so rarely used, it doesn't come up often.

Comment: I guess I've never heard "deck".  But then I haven't played with C++ much.  I would tend to pronounce it D-Q, since "dequeue" is often shortened to "deque" in other programming environments.

Comment: @HotLicks (and Armen): It's not specific to C++.  The concept has been around for a long time, definitely predating C++; and computer science students of a certain age will likely have had to implement one themselves from lower-level building blocks.

Comment: @JohnY - I know the concept has been around for a long time.  Which is why I know that "dequeue" is sometimes shortened to "deque", eg.  I've implemented queues of various types many times.  I've just never heard the pronunciation "deck".

Comment: A deque is different than a queue in that you can add and subtract from either end at any time. In C++'s STL is also assured to not allocate memory for every element like a linked list, but do so in chunks like a vector for efficiency.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Were you implying that 'earl' is incorrect for URL, or are you giving it as an example of things that different people say differently?  There are definitely people that use that pronunciation--I have no doubt that some prefer it for its quirkiness.

gif [hard or soft g], png ["ping" or P-N-G], SQL ["sequel" or S-Q-L] are other examples.

The only caveat I would add is that occasionally you run into a pronunciation that marks you as a newbie.  In the case of SQL, that can apparently go either way (see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7231/how-is-sql-pronounced?rq=1).

Comment: @msouth PNG is easy: the developers of the format explicitly specified the pronunciation to be "ping". Unfortunately, this is an exception; the creators of most other new words in the computer world just leave you hanging.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

From *The Art of Computer Programming*, volume 1, section 2.2.1 "Stacks, Queues, and Deques":

> A *deque* ("double-ended queue") is a linear list for which all insertions and deletions (and usually all accesses) are made at the ends of the list.  A deque is therefore more general than a stack or a queue; it has some properties in common with a deck of cards, and it is pronounced the same way.

It's pronounced /dɛk/, just like the word *deck*, as in a deck of cards.

Comment: Knuth is always right in the end. [If he wasn't, he would be broke.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_reward_check) To say he wrote the book on all there is to know about computer programming would be the understatement of all time.

Comment: I search on how to pronounce 'Dequer' whereas it is a last name of someone. I assume it is pronounced as 'deck-er', correct?

Answer (score 30):

It is most commonly pronounced the same as "deck," usually to distinguish it from a "de-queue" operation.  And so, you can "de-queue an object from the deque."

Comment: It also functions the same way as a deck of cards - it is easy to take one card off either end of the deck, but harder to extract an individual card from the center of the deck.  That similarity suggests that "deck" was the intended pronunciation.

Comment: That would be unqueue, no?

Comment: @J.C.Salomon I don't think so, because the verb to put something on the queue is to "enqueue" it, and that would sound almost exactly the same.

Comment: @undefined Wow, now I wish the data structure was simply called "deck". That analogy is perfect.

Answer (score 10):

I realize your question specifically mentions C++, but in Java there is a standard interface *java.lang.Deque*. The official *Javadoc for [Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html)* reads (in part):

> The name deque is short for "double ended queue" and is usually pronounced "deck".

The wikipedia for [Double-ended queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue) says

> dequeue, often abbreviated to deque, pronounced deck

and

> *Deque* is sometimes written *dequeue*, but this use is generally deprecated in technical literature or technical writing because *dequeue* is also a verb meaning "to remove from a queue".

Answer (score -6):

It is pronounced "deek," like the hockey maneouvre.

Comment: Would you care to provide some citations?