# "Indexes" or "indices"

Tags: grammatical-number, morphology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the plural of the word “index”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3123/what-is-the-plural-of-the-word-index)

I have a vague thought that *indices* would be used when *index* refers to a position in a sequential collection of some sort, but *indexes* is used when *index* itself refers to a collection of values.

> One index in the sequence. Several **indices** in the sequence.
>
> One book index. Many book **indexes**.

Is this correct?

Comment: I'd agree with your interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

AmEng seems to prefer *indexes* in all contexts. BrEng is more inclined to *indices*, particularly in mathematics and when describing economic and social indicators. It may also be used in BrEng to describe more than one index at the back of a book, but there, as you suggest, *indexes* is probably more common.

Comment: The Society of Indexers (a British and Irish professional body) insists on *indexes* at the back of a book.